# Executing a multi-line python script via bash

Tags: python, bash, smtp, quotes

I have a python script that scrapes matchups and stats of NHL teams to predict winners. The output of this script gives some general stats of the teams playing and predicts a winner, formatted as:

```
MATCHUP: San Jose Sharks ---- Anaheim Ducks
PTS%: 0.45 ---- 0.472
CF%: 50.7 ---- 48.0
5v5 Goals For per Game: 1.743 ---- 1.817
5v5 Goals Against per Game: 2.286 ---- 2.07
Power Play %: 17.46 ---- 14.67
Penalty Kill %: 85.71 ---- 77.0
Save Percentage: 0.889 ---- 0.908

Pick: San Jose Sharks.
Confidence: 15.8%.
```

Now I also have a shell script that I want to use to execute my python script daily (probably using crontab but haven't gotten there yet) and email me the results using smtp, that shell script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

messagebody=$(python3 nhlpredictions.py)

echo $messagebody | mail -s "$d NHLpredictions" ME@gmail.com
```

This works and I receive the email, however the output is formatted as a single line:

```
MATCHUP: San Jose Sharks ---- Anaheim Ducks PTS%: 0.45 ---- 0.472 CF%: 50.7 ---- 48.0 5v5 Goals For per Game: 1.743 ---- 1.817 5v5 Goals Against per Game: 2.286 ---- 2.07 Power Play %: 17.46 ---- 14.67 Penalty Kill %: 85.71 ---- 77.0 Save Percentage: 0.889 ---- 0.908 Pick: San Jose Sharks. Confidence: 15.8%.
```

I think this is happening because I'm saving the output of my python script to a single variable in bash. Is there any way around this so that the email I receive is formatted in the same way as the python script output (ie multiple lines)? Hopefully I can get this working before the season restarts, any advice would be helpful, thanks!

Comment: Could you post the part of your Python script where you're building that output?

Comment: easily you can execute python script with redirecting `>>` that will store the output into file `python3 nhlpredictions.py >> text.txt` then instead of `echo $messagebody` you can  do `cat text.txt`

Comment: This works. Thank you Mahmoud. I think I'll just have to rm text.txt after emailing so that my email doesn't get longer each day.

Comment: @chriswar no need you can rename the file with current date `python3 nhlpredictions.py >> text-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).txt`  also you can overwrite `>` will empty and overwrite the file.,  accept the answer, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the >> redirection operator will append lines to the end of the specified file, where-as the single greater than > will empty and overwrite the file.

Send stdout to a file
`python3 nhlpredictions.py >> text.txt`

then you can use `cat` to concatenate file and print on the standard output

```
#!/bin/bash

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
python3 nhlpredictions.py >> text.txt

cat text.txt | mail -s "$d NHLpredictions" ME@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose strings with `"` to ensure that they keep their newlines.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

d=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)

messagebody="$(python3 nhlpredictions.py)"

echo "$messagebody" | mail -s "$d NHLpredictions" ME@gmail.com
```

Answer (score -1):

Add parameter `-e` after echo.

```
echo -e $messagebody | mail -s "$d NHLpredictions" ME@gmail.com
```

If it doesn't work check if your variable contains the symbols `\n`.